# AQGridView: How to Init cell

Tags: objective-c, ipad, grid, aqgridview

I'm implementing the AQGridView based on examples who comes with it. But I'm working with xibs, and in the example, the code is:

```
 if ( plainCell == nil )
        {
            plainCell = [[[ImageDemoGridViewCell alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 150.0)
                                                 reuseIdentifier: PlainCellIdentifier] autorelease];
            plainCell.selectionGlowColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }

        plainCell.image = [UIImage imageNamed: [_imageNames objectAtIndex: index]];

        cell = plainCell;

    }
```

My code looks like this:

```
- (AQGridViewCell *) gridView: (AQGridView *)inGridView cellForItemAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index
  {


static NSString * FilledCellIdentifier = @"FilledCellIdentifier";

AQGridViewCell * cell = nil;

MagazineCell * filledCell = (MagazineCell *)[gridView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: FilledCellIdentifier];

if ( filledCell == nil ) {


}

filledCell.edicaoLabel.text = [[data objectAtIndex:index] name];

cell = filledCell;

return ( cell );
```

}

The example InitWith CGRect, but how init the cell when I work with xibs?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, one doesn't init a view when loading it from XIB.  You actually would do the same thing inside your if (filledCell == nil) that you would do in a UITableView (although with a AQGridViewCell instead of a UITableViewCell).  So if  "GridCell.xib" has your AQGridViewController as File Owner and tempCell is bound to the laid-out GridCell in IB and you've set the identifer to filledCellIdentifer, you can just do:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GridCell" owner:self options:nil]; 
filledCell = [self.tempCell autorelease];
```